# Clear Calendar.HOUR does not work on Android

Tags: android, calendar

That should be trivial: I want to remove all time information and leave just day set:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
log.debug("{}", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
log.debug("{}", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
log.debug("{}", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
log.debug("{}", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
log.debug("{}", calendar.getTimeInMillis());
String today = format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

But it leaves hour set:

```
06-03 07:14:31.296 1464930871295
06-03 07:14:31.297 1464930871295
06-03 07:14:31.297 1464930031295
06-03 07:14:31.298 1464930000295
06-03 07:14:31.299 1464930000000
06-03 07:14:31.300 Date is Thu Jun 02 07:00:00 GMT+02:00 2016
```

Why?

**Update**

[Android javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#clear(int)) might be wrong, as some answers point out:

> Clears the value in the given time field, marking it unset and
>   assigning it a value of zero. The actual field value will be
>   determined the next time the field is accessed.

Comment: what suppose if you do `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);` ?

Comment: The HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR and AM_PM fields are handled independently and the the resolution rule for the time of day is applied. Clearing one of the fields doesn't reset the hour of day value of this Calendar. Use set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) to reset the hour value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Javadoc of Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear-int-) and the [Android Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#clear%28int%29), too says to use `set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)` (for hour only) instead:

> The HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR and AM_PM fields are handled independently and
>   the the resolution rule for the time of day is applied. Clearing one
>   of the fields doesn't reset the hour of day value of this Calendar.
>   Use set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0) to reset the hour value.

Comment: Android javadoc is different. Thanks anyway, I will try, but I have to leave now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to clear units other than date is to set all units to 0 or default minimum by below way

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

String today = format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of Calendar about `clear(int field)`:

```
Clears the value in the given time field, marking it unset and assigning it a value of zero. 
The actual field value will be determined the next time the field is accessed.
```

So, when you call `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` in `Log` the value is set again. If you want to see how the method works, you can set a breakpoint there and debug it, to see how the values reset.